# How to track lines in large log file that don't appear in the expected order?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a large log file which includes lines in the format

```
id_number message_type
```

Here is an example for a log file where all lines appear in the expected order

```
1 A
2 A
1 B
1 C
2 B
2 C
```

However, not all lines appear in the expected order in my log file and I'd like to get a list of all id numbers that don't appear in expected order. For the following file

```
1 A
2 A
1 C
1 B
2 B
2 C
```

I would like to get an output that indicates id number 1 has lines that don't appear in the expected order. How to do this, using `grep`, `sed` and `awk`?

Comment: How many id's are there? Do gaps constitute "out of order" - I mean is 1A, 1C, 1D, 1E ok or out of order? Are the message types really, literally A, B, C? Or more complicated?

Comment: There are at least 10000 id numbers but can be much more. The types are A, B and C exactly as I described above. No gaps exist, only unexpected order of messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
awk -v "a=ABC" 'substr(a, b[$1]++ + 1, 1) != $2 {print $1}' logfile
```

When you run this, the ID number from each out-of-order line will be printed.  If there are no out-of-order lines, then nothing is printed.

#### How it works

- `-v "a=ABC"`

  This defines the variable `a` with the list of characters in their expected order.
- `substr(a, b[$1]++ + 1, 1) != $2 {print $1}`

  For each ID number, the array `b` keeps track of where we are.  Initially, `b` is zero for all IDs.  With this initial value, that is `b[$1]==0`, the expression `substr(a, b[$1] + 1, 1)` returns `A` which is our first expected output.  The condition `substr(a, b[$1] + 1, 1) != $2` thus checks if the expected output, from the `substr` function, differs from the actual output shown in the second field, `$2`.  If it does differ, then the ID value, `$1`, is printed.

  After the `substr` expression is computed, the trailing `++` in the expression `b[$1]++` increments the value of `b[$1]` by 1 so that the value of `b[$1]` is ready for the next time that ID `$1` is encountered.

#### Refinement

The above prints an ID number every time an out-of-order line is encountered.  If you just want each bad ID printed once, not multiple times, use:

```
awk -v "a=ABC" 'substr(a, b[$1]++ + 1, 1) != $2 {bad[$1]++} END{for (n in bad) print n}'  logfile
```

Answer (score 1):

I am only on my iPad with no way to test this, but I can give you an idea how to do it with `awk` since no-one else is answering...

Something like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<10000;i++)expected[i]=ord("A")}
     {if(expected[$1]!=ord($2))
         print "Out of order at line ", NR, $0;
      expected[i]=ord($2)+1
     }' yourFile
```

You will need to paste in the `ord()` function from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ordinal-Functions.html).

Basically, the concept is to initialise an array called `expected[]` that keeps track of the next message type expected for each `id` and then, as each line is read, check it is the next expected value.

Answer (score 1):

Batch only (last sort is not mandatory)

```
sort -k1n YourFile | tee file1 | sort -k2 > file2 && comm -23 file1 file2 | sort
```